# Accessing object defined in Tkinter App from Frame

Tags: python, class, tkinter

As it stands I have a code that defines a tkinter app (myGUI), and within that app various pages are defined as tk.Frames. I want the top section of each Frame to have the same base layout, so I define that in the class myGUI (as opposed to implementing it in every page).

Below is a simplified code (that works) with only one Frame defined (for simplicity). In this example a button 'main_page_button' is defined, and appears as expected when the code is run, what I want to know is how I can amend this button later on from the Frame 'MainPage', as is shown in the commented out line: `main_page_button.configure(bg='#0000FF')`.

I have tried a number of combinations of defining the button with self or frame, and also using the likes of self, parent, or controller when trying to access this element from the frame, however all this has shown me is that I don't fully understand the inner workings of what is going on within my code. So I would appreciate a solution to this problem, and bonus points if you can clear up the relationship between the App and Frame. If I've left something unclear feel free to ask, thanks!

Also, I realise I could probably call on a separate function from each Frame to reduce the repetition in my code, but for my own understanding I'd like to know how to achieve this the current way that I'm trying.

```
import tkinter as tk

class myGUI(tk.Tk):  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True) #Find out what this is doing **
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)          
        
        self.frames = {}  
    
        for F in [MainPage]: # Normally have more pages here

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
            frame.config(bg="#666666")

            main_page_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Main Page", background='#123456', font=("Verdana", 14, 'bold'), command='')
            main_page_button.place(relx=1/8,rely=0.00, relwidth=0.25, anchor='n')

        self.show_page(MainPage) #First page to be shown

    def show_page(self, cont):  

        frame = self.frames[cont]  
        frame.tkraise()


class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        #main_page_button.configure(bg='#0000FF')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = myGUI()
    app.state('zoomed')
    app.mainloop()
```

I haven't been able to find a similar question online, but if I've missed one please let me know and I will delete my question.

Comment: What's the point in creating a class to define a page, and then add widgets from outside the class? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Are you adding this button to every page  you create? Do you plan on adding lots of other widgets from outside the page class?

Comment: I just want to see if I can add a few widgets that will be present on every page, and then ultimately I want to be able to tweak one of those buttons on each page (to show that it is selected) if possible. Outside of that all other widgets specific to each page will be defined within the appropriate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a *base class* to do the common stuff and other pages inherit from it:

```py
 class myGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True) #Find out what this is doing **
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in [MainPage]: # Normally have more pages here

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
            frame.config(bg="#666666")

        self.show_page(MainPage) #First page to be shown

    def show_page(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

# base class
class BasePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, name):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.controller = controller

        # create the common button
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text=name, background='#123456', font=("Verdana", 14, 'bold'))
        self.button.place(relx=1/8, relwidth=0.25, anchor='n')

# inherits from BasePage
class MainPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller, "Main Page")
        # configure the button
        self.button.configure(bg='#00FF00')
```